# Remove a node and an ID attribute with position value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file:

```
<ROWS>
<ROW type="x" id="1">
<Test>text</Test>
</ROW>
<ROW type="x" id="1">
<Test>text</Test>
</ROW>
<ROW type="y" id="2">
<Test>text</Test>
</ROW>
<ROW type="x" id="3">
<Test>text</Test>
</ROW>
</ROWS>
```

I have to remove the row with attribute type "y" and attribute id value should be in in increment order:

```
<ROWS>
    <ROW type="x" id="1">
    <Test>text</Test>
    </ROW>
    <ROW type="x" id="2">
    <Test>text</Test>
    </ROW>
    <ROW type="x" id="3">
    <Test>text</Test>
    </ROW>
    </ROWS>
```

I tried with following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="ROWS/ROW[not(@type = 'y')]">
        <xsl:variable name="RowID">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <ROW id="{$RowID}" type="{@type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ROW>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ROW[@type='y']"/>
```

But it didn't work, I also used priority function but no success.

Can someone help? The most import part is id value, it should be in increment even after removing a Row of any type, for example in this case it is "y".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to remove the row with attribute type "y" and attribute id
>   value should be in in increment order

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ROWS">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW[not(@type='y')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROW">
    <ROW type="{@type}" id="{position()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </ROW>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you explain why position() returns the correct value in this solution but not if you use position() with the initial template match attempt of the OP?

Comment: Standard says: The position function returns a number equal to the context position from the expression evaluation context. I.e. in first case we have all ROW elements in context and position of ROW with id=3 is 4. In second case we have only ROW[@id!=y] elements in context an position returns proper value.

Comment: @rene In simple words: I only apply templates to *some* ROWs, not all of them. The position() function works from that. Technically, this is known as the *current node list* - see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#dt-current-node-list and also: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Node-Set-Functions

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/ROWS">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW[@type!='y']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROW">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <!-- here were have only proper elements in context, that's why we can use position() -->
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have several issues, among them: • Your output has no root element; •  This: `@*[.!='id']` selects nothing because there's no attribute that contains the string `id`; besides, it's not necessary since you're overwriting the attribute anyway; • Making every instance count the preceding nodes is inefficient; using xsl:number or position() whenever possible is preferable. • Your output contains the text values of the removed ROWs, due to the built-in template being applied to them.

Comment: @*[.!='id'] - yes, my fault. Should use name()

Comment: position()/xsl:number - not in this case because template is called in the context of all ROW elements.

Comment: Hi guys, none of the solution worked. the node with type "y" didnt get removed and id has values like 2,4,6,8 etc.... any idea?

Comment: Hi, It worked now. I just removed / from <xsl:template match="/ROWS"> to <xsl:template match="ROWS">. Thanks guys, it was a great help, much appreciated.